# Remove or manipulate parameters in controller

Tags: controllers, parameter

I am trying to remove a parameter under certain conditions when it is passed to my controller.  The var_dump of the request contains all the parameters.  The parameter I want to remove is called super_attribute.  Let's take a look at that var_dump shall we?

```
[product] => 10
[form_key] => XXYY
[related_product] => 
[super_attribute] => Array
    (
        [220] => 1141
    )
```

I am able to set the product parameter to another figure using:

```
$this->getRequest()->setParam('product', $product->getId());
```

However, I would like to know a way to altogether remove the super attribute or null it's array, heck, or even just change the values contained within!  For starters:

```
$this->getRequest()->setparam('super_attribute', null);
```

nor

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
unset($params['super_attribute']);
```

hold any water.

Comment: Try `$this->getRequest()->setPost('super_attribute', null)`. If that don't work take a look at `setRequest(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http $request)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look how method `Zend_Controller_Request_Http::getParams` works:

```
public function getParams()
{
    $return       = $this->_params;
    $paramSources = $this->getParamSources();
    if (in_array('_GET', $paramSources)
        && isset($_GET)
        && is_array($_GET)
    ) {
        $return += $_GET;
    }
    if (in_array('_POST', $paramSources)
        && isset($_POST)
        && is_array($_POST)
    ) {
        $return += $_POST;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

It all time gets parameters from global array and doesn't store it in class properties.

So there are two options you have:

- change `$_POST` strictly (eg `if (isset($_POST['super_attribute'])) { unset($_POST['super_attribute']); }` ).
- or you can use `$this->getRequest()->setPostValue('super_attribute', null)`. In that case key `super_attribute` wont be removed from `$_POST` array, but will be modified.